# Can anyone explain how this block of code work?

Tags: java, char, anagram, charat

I'm trying to understand this piece of code where it checks the anagrams of 2 different strings.

```
int[] charSet = new int[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < sA.length(); i++) {
        charSet[sA.charAt(i)]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sB.length(); i++) {
        charSet[sB.charAt(i)]--;
    }

    int deletion = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        deletion += Math.abs(charSet[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("The amount of deletion needed: " + deletion);
```

I used debugging to really grasp the idea of placing the char indexes in an array but when i check the content of the array there are either 0's or 1's. But isn't `sA.charat(i)` returns the index of the string not 0 or 1?

So `charSet[sA.charAt(i)]++;` what does this code really do as to my understanding it gets the char index of the string and adds to the array but what is the point of `++` ?

Also, more specifically, `deletion += Math.abs(charSet[i]);` how does this line of code work because all it does is adds the corresponding index of an array on top of another. But i don't really understand how this work to check anagrams of 2 strings.

I really will appreciate if anyone can explain this in detail.

Comment: No, `String.charAt(i)` returns the character **value** at character position `i`.

Comment: *"But isn't `sA.charat(i)` returns the index of the string"* No, `charAt` returns the `char` at the given index. The `char` is likely a letter (A-Z), and the ASCII value (65-90) is then the index into the `charSet` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the purpose and behaviour of `charSet[sA.charAt(i)]++;`. As soon as you understand why that line is there, everything else becomes straightforward.

`charSet` here is counting how many of each char the first string has. For example, if the string were `aab`, then index 97 of `charSet` will be `2`, index 98 will be `1`, and the rest will be all 0s. The `int` value for "a" is 97 and the `int` value for "b" is 98.

The first for loop loops through each character of the first string. `charSet[sA.charAt(i)]++;` basically increments the count of that character by 1. For the string `aab`, the expression evaluates to:

```
// note that charAt(i) returns the character at index i of the string
charSet[97]++; // 1st iteration
charSet[97]++; // 2nd iteration
charSet[98]++; // 3rd iteration
```

Now the second for loop does the reverse to the second string. This time, we count down. Why? Because if the two strings are anagrams, we would end up with `charSet` filled with 0s, after counting up the characters and counting down the same characters.

Let's say that the two strings are not anagrams. This means that after the first two for loops, `charSet` contains some non-0s. We add the absolute value of these non-0s up to get how many characters needs to be added/removed to make the two strings anagrams.

---

Note that this program will crash if the strings contain characters that has values that are more than 256! A better way to solve this problem would be to use a `HashMap` to count the characters.

Comment: After reading the above explanations + this, i really got the concept now. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: 256 means the program is limited to the C0 Controls and Basic Latin and 
C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement [Unicode blocks](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). 

Answer (score 0):

The charSet represents 256 different possible values of the char primitive type.
There are a lot more, as noted by biziclop and Andreas in the comments.

The two strings, which are essentially arrays of chars, are iterated.
The charSet array basically keeps a count of the occurrence of each char in the strings.
For the first string, the count is increased by one for each occurrence, for the second, the count is decreased by one. As such, if the strings are anagrams of each other, every int in the charSet array should be 0.

Finally, the charSet array is iterated to sum up missing chars between the strings. You could consider the deletion variable as a measure of difference between the strings.

Comment: The `char` primitive type has far more than 256 possible values. It's just that this program only deals with the first 256, therefore it fails if it encounters a character out of that range.

Comment: *"The char primitive type in Java has 256 possible values"* Wrong. a `char` is a UTF-16 encoded 2-byte value of a Unicode character, so it has more than 60000 values *(not all 65536 values are valid)*.

Comment: True, I forgot about that. Will change it.

Comment: @Andreas We made exactly the same comments in exactly the same order :)

Answer (score 0):

Anagrams are words or phrases which can be formed by rearranging the letters of another word. eg `pale -> leap`. Both these words use the same set of letters i.e `l, a, p, e`

The code you shared is following a logic where it initializes an empty integer array of length 256 to include all lowercase, uppercase, special chars etc.

It first of all loops through each letter in first string and increments the count in the integer array for the ascii value of the letter.

Then it loops through each letter in second string and decrements the count in the integer array for the ascii value of the letter.

The logic behind this is that if both strings are anagrams which means they use the same set of characters. If that is the case then after both iterations, value of every element in int array would still remain equal to zero. If any value is greater than or less than zero, then it means that there is a discrepancy in the letters used in both strings and hence they are not anagrams.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getDeletion(String sA, String sB) {
    //this creates an array with 256 items, so that is an item for all the characters.
    int[] charSet = new int[256];

    //This goes through each letter of sA, and it increments the value at the value of the current letter in ASCII
    //So if the first letter is A , it will increment the 65th item of charSet, because 65 is the ASCII value of a.
    //It does this for all letters of sA.
    for (int i = 0; i < sA.length(); i++) {
        charSet[sA.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    //It does the same here for sB, but it subtracts the value.
    for (int i = 0; i < sB.length(); i++) {
        charSet[sB.charAt(i)]--;
    }

    //now we have at each item of charSet the amount of difference between the two strings for each letter.
    //So if sA has 2 As and sB has 1 A, item 65 of charSet will be 1.
    //If sA has 1 A and sB has 2 As, item 65 of charSet will be -1.

    int deletion = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        //Here we add the amount of difference from each character to the 'deletion' variable. This will give us a total difference score.
        //The Math.abs() makes sure the item is positive (so -5 will become 5).
        deletion += Math.abs(charSet[i]);
    }
    return deletion;

    //So say we compare "adc" and "bca". After the 2nd for loop, each item of charSet is 0, except value 98 and 100 
    //(ASCII value for b and c respectively).
    //value 98 will be -1, because sB has 1 more b than sA
    //value 100 will be 1, because sA has 1 more d than sB
    //The -1 will be converted to a 1, because of the Math.abs()
    //So in the for loop every value is added up to become 2, which is returned.
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate this detailed commenting, i now fully grasp the works of it. Thank you.